# Table, i.e. the piece of furniture on which one eats, in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How would you draw a table, i.e. the piece of furniture on which one eats, like the following in Tikz? As always, I am very grateful for your clever tikz constructions!
[image: table attacked by arrows]

Comment: There is a website http://www.texample.net/ which lists a lot of TikZ examples. Have a look if you find what you are looking for there. If not it would be a good idea to upload the solution to your drawing request there, so other people find them more easily.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I plan on doing just that at the end of the project on which Im currently working! From what I understand, the license under which answers appear here allows this kind of cross-posting as long as I link back to the original answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a crude solution. With time and refactoring, an elegant solution may be written up.

The key part is to use the 3-dimensional coordinate system.

I only drew the table.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=lightgray]

%legs
\foreach \leg in {(0.3,0,0),(4.9,0,0),(4.9,0,-2.7),(0.3,0,-2.7)}{
\begin{scope}[shift=\leg,draw=red]
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,-0.2) -- (0,2,-0.2) -- (0,2,0);
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) rectangle (-0.2,2,0);
\end{scope}}

%table
\begin{scope}[draw=blue,shift={(0,2,0)}]
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) -- (5,0,-3) -- (0,0,-3) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) -- (5,-0.1,0)-- (0,-0.1,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill] (5,0,0) -- (5,0,-3) -- (5,-0.1,-3)-- (5,-0.1,0) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is

[image]

Hera is another version of the code. It is longer, but it uses macros defined at the beginning, to make it easier to modify the table.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=lightgray]

%table dimensions
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tablelength}{5};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tablewidth}{3};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tablethickness}{0.2};

%leg dimensions
\pgfmathsetmacro{\leglength}{\tablewidth};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\halflegwidth}{0.5*\tablethickness};

\pgfmathsetmacro{\shift}{2*\halflegwidth};

%legs
\foreach \leg in {(0+\shift,0,0),(\tablelength-\shift,0,-\shift),
                  (\tablelength-\shift,0,-\tablewidth+\shift),
                  (0+\shift,0,-\tablewidth+\shift)}{
    \path[shift=\leg,draw=red,fill] 
        (\halflegwidth,0,\halflegwidth) -- (\halflegwidth,0,-\halflegwidth) -- 
        (\halflegwidth,\leglength,-\halflegwidth) --    
               (\halflegwidth,\leglength,\halflegwidth)

        (\halflegwidth,0,\halflegwidth) rectangle 
              (-\halflegwidth,\leglength,\halflegwidth);
}

%table
\path[draw=blue,shift={(0,\leglength,0)},fill]
    (0,0,0) -- (\tablelength,0,0) -- (\tablelength,0,-\tablewidth) -- 
     (0,0,-\tablewidth) -- cycle

    (0,0,0) -- (\tablelength,0,0) -- (\tablelength,-\tablethickness,0)--
     (0,-\tablethickness,0) -- cycle

    (\tablelength,0,0) -- (\tablelength,0,-\tablewidth) -- 
     (\tablelength,-\tablethickness,-\tablewidth)--
    (\tablelength,-\tablethickness,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Merci, Frédéric!