# How to construct a box in the first page of this template to enter text?

Tags: beamer, sharelatex

Hello I am working with the template called: Radboud University Beamer(Version1),
https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations, this is a beautiful template however I would like to customize it a little.

Since I changed the image of background of the first page, I am using a picture of my university, in the following part:

```
% Background
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{myImage}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}
```

Of the file called ru.sty, the text that I am using for the author of the presentation at the following part:

```
\author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
  Pim Vullers MSc \\\medskip
  {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl}} \\ 
  {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}

    % The institute:
%  - to start the name of the university as displayed on the top of each slide
%    this can be adjusted such that you can also create a Dutch version
%  - next the institute information as displayed on the title slide
\institute[School of science]{
  Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
  Radboud University Nijmegen}

% Add a date and possibly the name of the event to the slides
%  - again first a short version to be shown at the bottom of each slide
%  - second the full date and event name for the title slide
\date[slides Example 2010]{
  the 1st example presentation 2010 \\
  7th October 2010}
```

Appears not so clear, to fix this I would like to enter a box o another color to make contrast,  I tried:

```
\begin{block}{A box to enter text}

\author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
  Pim Vullers MSc \\\medskip
  {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl}} \\ 
  {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}

% The institute:
%  - to start the name of the university as displayed on the top of each slide
%    this can be adjusted such that you can also create a Dutch version
%  - next the institute information as displayed on the title slide
\institute[School of Science]{
  Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
  Radboud University Nijmegen}

% Add a date and possibly the name of the event to the slides
%  - again first a short version to be shown at the bottom of each slide
%  - second the full date and event name for the title slide
\date[slides Example 2010]{
  the 1st example presentation 2010 \\
  7th October 2010}


\end{block}
```

But I failed since the box is shown before the title of the presentation and is not displaying the information.

I am not sure why is failing since I made a prove and I create another frame of the presentation, just to test this function and it worked well, however I believe that due to the fact that I want to alter the first page of the presentation maybe I need to use a distinct approach, I would like to receive any advice to overcome this situation, thanks any how.

```
\section{Background information2}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information2}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Example of a box \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}

    Some text
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

To add more details the original code for the main two parts of the template is the following, ru.sty

```
% Copyright 2009 by Pim Vullers
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.



%%%
%%% Inherit definitions from existing themes (DO NOT MODIFY THESE)
%%%

% Layout scheme for outer elements: split header and footer
\useoutertheme{split}

% Color scheme for outer elements: use background colors
\usecolortheme{whale}

% Layout scheme for inner elements: rounded elements
\useinnertheme{rounded} 

% Color scheme for inner elements: use foreground colors
\usecolortheme{orchid}


%%%
%%% Tweak definitions of inner theme to match personal preferences (MODIFY THESE)
%%%

% Itemize items: default (triangle), circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

% Enumerate items: default, circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]

% Outline: default, sections numbered, subsections numbered, circle, square, ball, ball unnumbered
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

% General blocks: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]

% Title page:
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

% Part page:
\setbeamertemplate{part page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

% Navigation symbols:
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


%%%
%%% Tweak definitions of outer theme to match Radboud (website) style
%%%

% Background
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{myImage}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}

% Colors
\usecolortheme[RGB={190,49,26}]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(frametitle.bg);
  color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle right.bg)}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
}

% Footline: AUTHOR | TITLE | DATE FRAMENUMBER

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.416667\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.083333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ru theme}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  %\vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0.1mm}{0pt}{1.01\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
%  \nointerlineskip
%    \vskip-0.2pt
%    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
%    \vskip-2pt
}
```

example.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,ru,url}

% The title of the presentation:
%  - first a short version which is visible at the bottom of each slide;
%  - second the full title shown on the title slide;
\title[RU style for Beamer]{
  Radboud University style for Beamer \LaTeX}

% Optional: a subtitle to be dispalyed on the title slide
\subtitle{Show where you're from}

% The author(s) of the presentation:
%  - again first a short version to be displayed at the bottom;
%  - next the full list of authors, which may include contact information;
\author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
  Pim Vullers MSc \\\medskip
  {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl}} \\ 
  {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}

% The institute:
%  - to start the name of the university as displayed on the top of each slide
%    this can be adjusted such that you can also create a Dutch version
%  - next the institute information as displayed on the title slide
\institute[Radboud University Nijmegen]{
  Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
  Radboud University Nijmegen}

% Add a date and possibly the name of the event to the slides
%  - again first a short version to be shown at the bottom of each slide
%  - second the full date and event name for the title slide
\date[slides Example 2010]{
  the 1st example presentation 2010 \\
  7th October 2010}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% Section titles are shown in at the top of the slides with the current section 
% highlighted. Note that the number of sections determines the size of the top 
% bar, and hence the university name and logo. If you do not add any sections 
% they will not be visible.
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is just a short example
    \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
    \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
    \item The style is based on the webpage \url{http://www.ru.nl/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Background information}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Beamer offers a lot of functions to create nice slides using \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}
    This style uses the following default styles:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item split
      \item whale
      \item rounded
      \item orchid
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{The important things}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The important things}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This just shows the effect of the style
    \item It is not a Beamer tutorial
    \item Read the Beamer manual for more help
    \item Contact me only concerning the style file
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Analysis of the work}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Analysis of the work}

  This style file gives your slides some nice Radboud branding.
  When you know how to work with the Beamer package it is easy to use.
  Just add:\\ ~~~$\backslash$usepackage$\{$ru$\}$ \\ at the top of your file.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy to use
    \item Good results
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach won't work, as `\author` etc. are just macros to store the information, not to use them. So at the place you tried to insert the block, the document not even started.

However there are other possibilities. All the information are by default inside boxes. These boxes are transparent in your example, but you can set the colour

```
\setbeamercolor{author}{parent=title}
\setbeamercolor{institute}{parent=title}
\setbeamercolor{date}{parent=title}
```

[image]

Or if you don't like this, you can define your own title page

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother
```

and insert whatever code you want there.

Comment: Amezing, This what I wanted, I really appreciate the support.

Comment: just another comment I realized that with a solid red the image of background is not visible, I tried changing the color of the box with \setbeamercolor{author}{fg=red!80!black,bg=red!20!white}, however this way gave me solid colors do you know how to get a red a little bit transparent?

Comment: @neo33 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44716/36296

Comment: I really appreciate the support I tried with that but again only work with blocks, it is not working with parts such as \author that as you explained me before are just macros to store the information...