# latex beamer title color font size

Tags: beamer, fonts, graphics, color

How can one change title, color, and font size in the beamer package ?

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

%\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\tiny}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0pt}
\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}
\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

%% Title slide formatting %%

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{titlebackground}{put here any image}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{

  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(-28.5,-163){%
    \pgfuseimage{titlebackground}
  } 
 \put(0,-75){%    

   \begin{minipage}[b][4.5cm][t]{0.65\textwidth}
   \color{white}            
 \usebeamerfont{title}                
   {\inserttitle\\[0.9cm]}              
 \usebeamerfont{subtitle}

 {\insertauthor\par}                   
 {\insertinstitute\\[0.3cm]}                 
  {\insertdate}           
\end{minipage}   
    }   
 \end{picture}
}

%% General slide formatting %%

\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{4,30,66}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=3.9cm]{oxfordlogo}{put here any image}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=1cm]{mathslogo}{put here any image}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(230,-45){%
            \pgfuseimage{oxfordlogo}
        }
        \put(20,-50){%
            \rule{320pt}{0.4pt}
        }
    \end{picture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(-8,-10){%
            \normalsize\color{oxfordblue}\insertframetitle
        }
        \put(-7,-20){%

            \tiny\color{oxfordblue}\insertframesubtitle
        }
    \end{picture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(20,30){% 
            \rule{320pt}{0.4pt}
        }
        \put(20,14){%
            %\pgfuseimage{mathslogo}
            \color{oxfordblue}\text{Jimyeong Lee (GSSI)}
        }
        \put(100,14){%
            \color{oxfordblue}\insertshortdate  
        }
        \put(160,14){%
            \color{oxfordblue}\insertshorttitle       
}
        \put(337,14){%
            \color{oxfordblue}\insertpagenumber  
        }
    \end{picture}%
}

%% Information (author, title, etc.) %%
\title[MATH]{MATH}% short title for footer
\author%
{%
    \sc{Ph.D. candidate: }\\
    \textit{Institute}
}
\institute%
{%
    \sc{Advisor: }\\
    \textit{Institute}
}
\date[\today]{Thesis Defense Presentation, \today} % short date for footer

%% Content of slides %%

\begin{document}

%   \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
%       \raisebox{1cm}{
%           \parbox[b]{10.5cm}{
%               %${\insertfootnotemark}$\insertfootnotetext
%           }
%   }}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    % TOC
    \begin{frame}{Contents}
        %\begin{multicols}{2}
            \tableofcontents
        %\end{multicols}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please make a compilable document. It is impossible to guess how your title may look like, as the definition just ends in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: You can compile if you put any image in "put here any image".

Answer (score 3):

To change the title font size, you can use the exact same mechanism as you already do for the subtitle: `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}`

The colour is a bit trickier as you define your title page yourself. If you add 
`\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}` to your custom title page, then you can change the colour via `\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue}`

Of-topic: you don't need `graphicx` with beamer and instead of `multicol` and `wallpaper` beamer has its own mechanism for columns and backgrounds.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

%% Title slide formatting %%
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{titlebackground}{example-image}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(-28.5,-163){%
    \pgfuseimage{titlebackground}
  }
 \put(0,-75){%
  \begin{minipage}[b][4.5cm][t]{0.65\textwidth}
    \color{white}
 \usebeamerfont{title}
   {\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\inserttitle\\[0.9cm]}
 \usebeamerfont{subtitle}
 {\insertauthor\par}
 {\insertinstitute\\[0.3cm]}
  {\insertdate}
\end{minipage}
   }
 \end{picture}
}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue}

%% General slide formatting %%
\definecolor{oxfordblue}{RGB}{4,30,66}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=3.9cm]{oxfordlogo}{example-image}
\pgfdeclareimage[width=1cm]{mathslogo}{example-image}

\title[MATH]{MATH}% short title for footer

\author{%
    \sc{Ph.D. candidate: }\\
    \textit{Institute}
}

\institute{%
    \sc{Advisor: }\\
    \textit{Institute}
}

\date[\today]{Thesis Defense Presentation, \today} 
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you more? If I change the subtitle color as as same as title did, then there is an indent how can I modify this? Also do you know the way how to make the background image color lighter which makes the title and subtilte more visible?

Comment: @Jimmy Concerning your indent problem: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates this problem. Probably there are some % missing in the code - but I cannot know unless I see the code

Comment: @Jimmy For the image: two options. Either edit the image in a graphic manipulation software of your choice (for example gimp) or you could place your text in semi-transparent boxes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337058/36296