# What tips and tricks are there for debugging TikZ/PGF code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, debugging

When answering questions here and when drawing my own complicated TikZ/PGF drawings, I've developed a fair number of "tips and tricks" for debugging the code.  I'm sure that others have as well.  I think it would be useful to accumulate a list of such, whence this question:

What are your tips and tricks for debugging TikZ/PGF code?

---

<sub>**Note:** in one sense this seems an obvious candidate for making Community Wiki as there is no single answer.  However, I think that these tricks take some ingenuity and so deserve to gain their authors a modicum of reputation, whence I'm reluctant to make it a CW question (of course, I'll donate all my reputation gained from this question to a worthy cause).  Once there are a fair few answers, I can see that organising them into a single CW answer would be a good thing, but that doesn't mean that the question should be CW.  On the other hand, whilst in favour of it not being CW, I wouldn't be in anyway upset if the feeling was that it should be CW.</sub>

Comment: In addition to your concerns, I would like to ask if *usage of QTikZ* counts as a tip. It is an indispensable tool for me to see where the error is but still, one might consider that this is not a tip or trick.

Comment: @percusse: I guess you’re using QTikZ with Linus, but do you know how I can build it for OS X?

Comment: @Tobi You can see the comments [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633/3235) which discusses Mac OSX case extensively.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks but it doen’t work. I don’t know why I guess I’m to stupid for install an app via Terminal. It’s always the same: I do exactly what the install guide say but it doesn’t work :-( (ps. Sorry Andrew for misusing your question …)

Comment: I have noticed in the past that TikZ/PGF is quite forgiving, unlike regular LaTeX, in the sense that adding non-existent or incorrectly located options/keywords, and sometimes syntax that is a bit wonky (sorry, vague) does not result in errors. Instead, TikZ/PGF just ignores the error(s). I was wondering if there was some way to make such mistakes more explicit. In other words, make the parsing more "strict".

Comment: (see also: [compiling - How to trace LaTeX errors efficiently? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/how-to-trace-latex-errors-efficiently?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 9):

I'll start off with the `show node name` key.  This is very useful when trying to work out why a complicated node name isn't working (often because a period has snuck in uninvited).

Here's the code:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  show node name/.code={%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@mode\expandafter{\tikz@mode\show\tikz@fig@name}%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

We add the `\show` code to the `\tikz@mode` macro to ensure that the node name is set by the time we're called.  Otherwise `\node[show node name] (hello) {};` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 8):

**Label Coordinates:**

I posted this as part of an answer on [How to draw a cube with TikZ where all faces have a distinct color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/how-to-draw-a-cube-with-tikz-where-all-faces-have-a-distinct-color/28286#28286), and while it is rather obvious, and I still use it, I feel that it might help new users.

At the end of a picture I add a `\foreach` loop to label all the important nodes so that I can see where they are:

```
%% Following is for debugging purposes so you can see where the points are
%% These are last so that they show up on top
\foreach \xy in {O, A, B, C, D, E, F, G}{
    \node at (\xy) {\xy};
}
```

This does require some discipline in not using coordinates without labeling them.  I never delete this code, but just comment it out as you never know when you have to come back and make tweaks.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes, one gets an error message without its context (like "could not read this number") -- and one wonders why and where.

What I do in this case is to add

```
\tracingmacros=2 \tracingcommands=2
```

somewhere before the offending position. This can easily produce hundreds of megabytes of .log files - but it will surely identify the position because it is a kind of "disassambly" of TeX.

As any other kind of disassembly it is hard to read. But if one aborts `latex` at its first error, one can scroll through the huge log file until one finds keywords which look familiar (in case of a wrong number, one may find the number parsing routine and its argument).

Comment: Note that a related way is to insert `\message{<text>^^J}` somewhere into your sources (or perhaps into `tikz.code.tex` ;-) ). The `^^J` causes a line break.

Answer (score 2):

When working with clips, it can be useful to actually render the paths to see if the path is what you expect it to be.  When doing this, use `\fill` and not `\draw`.  The reason is that clipped paths have to be closed so PGF will automatically close any unclosed path and this may introduce unexpected behaviour.  As `\fill` has the same behaviour, it is thus better for debugging than `\draw`.  As an extra, put an `opacity=.5` (or similar) to get the effect of seeing through (particularly useful for combining clips).

(This was actually the *direct* motivation for this question.)

Answer (score 1):

**Use Different Colors for Lines**

If I have copied the code from examples on this site, or in the case where
the coordinates are not easy to label, then I change the line colors to make it easy to see which line part of the code produces which portion of the diagram.

Here is a snippet of code from a recent [posting here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/is-there-a-way-to-draw-tikz-lines-on-the-inside-or-outside-of-a-path) that I was trying to understand:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,line width=2mm]
\draw [green](0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) -- (1,1,0) -- (0,1,0) -- cycle;
\draw [blue](1,0,0) -- (1,0,-1) -- (1,1,-1) -- (1,1,0) -- cycle;
\draw [red](0,1,0) -- (0,1,-1) -- (1,1,-1) -- (1,1,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this specific case it is not too hard to track the coordinates to see which line is which, but I find this extremely helpful in more complex cases.