# normal coordinate system in tikz using parallel curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I have a wavey looking curve and would like to show the corresponding normal coordinate system, which is defined by arclength along the curve and (signed) distance from the curve. So there should be lines normal to the curve (for arclength) and curves parallel to the original curve (for distance from the curve).

I am using the solution from [Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33607/easy-curves-in-tikz) to draw my wavey curve and [How to draw tangent line of an arbitrary point on a path in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25928/how-to-draw-tangent-line-of-an-arbitrary-point-on-a-path-in-tikz) to get the normal lines. I can draw a single parallel line using `double distance=1cm` from [How to raise a generic curve. Problem with \pgfdeclaredecoration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31707/how-to-raise-a-generic-curve-problem-with-pgfdeclaredecoration), but I'm not sure how to get a whole set of parallel lines.

Eventually I would also like nodes that label the lines/curves `s=1`, `s=2`, ..., `r=1`, `r=2`,...,`r=0`,`r=-1`,...

Here is my current code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzstyle{tangent}=[decoration={markings,% switch on markings
        mark= at position #1 with {
          \coordinate (tangent point-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,0pt);
          \coordinate (tangent unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (1,0pt);
          \coordinate (tangent orthogonal unit vector-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}) at (0pt,1); }}, postaction=decorate]

\tikzstyle{use tangent}=[
    shift=(tangent point-#1),
    x=(tangent unit vector-#1),
    y=(tangent orthogonal unit vector-#1)]


\tikzset{forcedist/.style={decorate, decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.0999 with {\draw[<-] (0,-#1) -- (0,#1); }}}}%Here
\tikzset{use tangent/.default=1}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
      \draw [cyan, double distance = 1cm, tangent=0.001,tangent=0.1,tangent=0.2,tangent=0.3,tangent=0.4,tangent=0.5,tangent=0.6,tangent=0.7,tangent=0.8,tangent=0.9,tangent=0.999] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,.5) (3,2) (7,1) (10,3)};
      \foreach \i in {1,...,11} { \draw [very thin,gray,use tangent=\i] (0,-4) -- (0,4); }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Do you also want the curve to scale when increasing and decreasing in +ve and -ve directions? Or is it going to be a shift all the way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by scaling and what "ve" refers to, but I'd like the curves to be constant distances apart, not just a shift up and to the side.

Comment: I meant *positive* and *negative*, constant distances apart alright but do they grow as in your example?

Comment: Do you mean do the lengths of the curves grow? If so, then sure, whatever requires them to maintain a constant distance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the manual, "double distance" is just a line with a large width...so here is a hackish way of producing what I wanted:

(using same preamble as above)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\foreach \i in {5,...,1} {
\draw [cyan, double distance = \i cm, tangent=0.001,tangent=0.1,tangent=0.2,tangent=0.3,tangent=0.4,tangent=0.5,tangent=0.6,tangent=0.7,tangent=0.8,tangent=0.9,tangent=0.999] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,.5) (3,2) (7,1) (10,3)}; }
\draw [cyan, tangent=0.001,tangent=0.1,tangent=0.2,tangent=0.3,tangent=0.4,tangent=0.5,tangent=0.6,tangent=0.7,tangent=0.8,tangent=0.9,tangent=0.999] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (0,.5) (3,2) (7,1) (10,3)}; 
\foreach \i in {1,...,11} { \draw [very thin,gray,use tangent=\i] (0,-4) -- (0,4); }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: image with normal coordinate system]

Please feel free to submit other answers, as I feel there should be a much more elegant way of doing this!!