# How can I shrink a path to the center?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm not quite sure if I formulated the title correctly.

I would like to get a result similar to the hand-drawn graph and I got the right one:

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{pink}{HTML}{FF00FF}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{800080}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning, calc,lindenmayersystems,decorations.pathmorphing} 
\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,fill=black,circle,minimum size=10pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
\tikzstyle{markedCircle}=[line width=1pt,rotate=90,decorate,decoration={snake, segment length=2mm, amplitude=0.4mm}]

\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}  [scale=1.2]
  \node (a)[vertex] at (3,1) {a};
  \node (b)[vertex] at (5.5,2.5) {b};
  \node (c)[vertex] at (0.5,3) {c};
  \node (d)[vertex] at (3.5,4.5) {d};
  \node (e)[vertex] at (6,5.5) {e};
  \node (f)[vertex] at (0,6.5) {f};
  \node (g)[vertex] at (3,7) {g};
  \node (h)[vertex] at (4.5,7.5) {h};
  \node (i)[vertex] at (6,7.5) {i};
  \node (j)[vertex] at (1.5,8.5) {j};
  \node (k)[vertex] at (4,9) {k};

  \foreach \from/\to in {a/b,a/b,b/d,b/e,c/f,d/f,d/g,f/g,g/h,h/e,h/i,e/i,f/j,g/j,j/k,k/h,k/i}
    \draw[line width=2pt] (\from) -- (\to);

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \draw (a.center) edge[selected edge] (c.center);
    \draw (c.center) edge[selected edge] (f.center);
    \draw (f.center) edge[selected edge] (g.center);
    \draw (g.center) edge[selected edge] (j.center);
    \draw (g.center) edge[selected edge] (h.center);
    \draw (h.center) edge[selected edge] (k.center);
    \draw (g.center) edge[selected edge] (d.center);
    \draw (d.center) edge[selected edge] (b.center);
    \draw (h.center) edge[selected edge] (i.center);
    \draw (h.center) edge[selected edge] (e.center);
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  % Can those be shrinked?
  \draw[color=black!80, markedCircle] (a) -- (c) -- (f) -- (g) -- (d) -- (b) -- (a);
  \draw[color=purple,   markedCircle, fill=purple!10] (f) -- (g) -- (d) -- (f);
  \draw[color=red,      markedCircle] (b) -- (d) -- (g) -- (h) -- (e) -- (b);
  \draw[color=yellow,   markedCircle] (g) -- (h) -- (k) -- (j) -- (g);
  \draw[color=pink,     markedCircle] (f) -- (g) -- (j) -- (f);
  \draw[color=pink,     markedCircle] (f) -- (g) -- (j) -- (f);
  \draw[color=orange,   markedCircle] (h) -- (k) -- (i) -- (h);
  \draw[color=blue,     markedCircle] (h) -- (i) -- (e) -- (h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to make two (or three) things:

- shrink the areas to the center so that the lines don't overlap
- write the numbers in the center of the area
- (perhaps find a more random solution - one that looks more like handwriting - for drawing the lines than snake)

(The current sources are on [GitHub](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/tikz/graph-circles). I will include the solution there, as soon as it is available.)

Comment: Well for the first one you could manually move the points so that the lines are inside, the numbers can just be nodes, and yes a hand written style can be added. Are you looking for an automated solutions for the first points?

Comment: adding the numbers could be done manually, but I am looking for an automated solution for moving the points inside. I thought this might be related to the problem of setting the numbers to the center, because if you keep shrinking the area, you will get to the center.

Comment: For the automation you should refer to [Is there a way to draw TikZ lines on the “inside” or “outside” of a path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/is-there-a-way-to-draw-tikz-lines-on-the-inside-or-outside-of-a-path/30102#30102). I attempted to work on your solution, but got confused when `($(f)+(-0.1,0.5)$)` move the point `f` to slightly below (y=-0.1), and more to the left (x=-0.5).  I did see you doing anything funny with the `x` and `y` vectors...  Perhaps I am just tired...

Comment: Looking at the picture that Alain Matthes has provided, I don't think that you want to shift each node towards the *centre* of the shape.  I think that you want to shift each node inwards along the bisector of two lines entering the node.  This will ensure that each wibbly path is a fixed distance from its true path whereas in Alain's picture then paths are different distances.

Answer (score 6):

You write the number in the center of each area with something like

```
  \node[text=black] at (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1 ,c=1,d=1,f=1) {\Large 1}; 
  \node[text=magenta] at (barycentric cs:f=1,g=1 ,j=1) {\Large 2};
```

It's possible to automate with a macro ( vertices = arguments )

A first possibility if you want to avoid overlaping
(update with your styles you need to add some arguments )

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  [scale=1.2]
  \node (a)[vertex] at (3,1) {a};
  \node (b)[vertex] at (5,2) {b};
  \node (c)[vertex] at (0,3) {c};

  \node[text=black] (o1) at (barycentric cs:a=1,b=1 ,c=1) {\Large 1}; 

\path (o1) -- coordinate[pos=.8] (a') (a.90);
\path (o1) -- coordinate[pos=.8] (b') (b.225); 
\path (o1) -- coordinate[pos=.8] (c') (c.-45);

  \draw[color=blue] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (a); 
  \draw[color=blue,     markedCircle] (a') -- (b') -- (c')--cycle;    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For drawing inside, I recommend using bisectors at each vertex.  An inelegant way to compute these is to use the `intersections` and `calc` library.  Using the `calc` library, we create (but don't draw) parallel lines to each of the lines in the polygon which are offset by a set amount to the inside of the polygon ("inside" is determined by the orientation in which the polygon is specified in the following - I said it was inelegant!).  Then the `intersections` library computes the intersections of pairs of these lines and sticks a node at each intersection.  These are then the inner offsets at each node.  (This only works if the polygons are convex, though could be adapted for non-convex polygons.)  Once these are established they can be used for drawing the lines.  To get a suitable type of line, try combining decorations (see Section 21.2, decorating subpaths, for more on that).

Here's some example code.  It would need a bit of polishing to make it automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82821/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (3,0);
\coordinate (c) at (5,3);
\draw (b) -- (a) -- (c) -- cycle;
\def\prev{a}
\def\this{b}
\def\offset{2mm}
\foreach \next in {c,a,b} {
  \path[name path=first] ($(\prev)!\offset!90:(\this)$) --
($(\this)!\offset!-90:(\prev)$);
  \path[name path=second] ($(\this)!\offset!90:(\next)$) --
($(\next)!\offset!-90:(\this)$);
  \path[name intersections={of=first and second}] coordinate
(\prev-\this-\next) at (intersection-1);
  \global\let\prev=\this
  \global\let\this=\next
}
\draw (a-b-c) -- (c-a-b) -- (b-c-a) -- cycle;
%\draw decorate[decoration={coil,aspect=0,amplitude=2pt}] {
decorate[decoration={random steps}] { (a-b-c) -- (c-a-b) -- (b-c-a) --
cycle }};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As written, the above produces:

[image: bisectors using TikZ]

If I swap the commenting on the last `\draw` commands, I get:

[image: wibbly bisectors]