# Corners of 3D cube extend beyond where they meet / tikz / draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

i figured out how to draw the 3d effect cubes, but now im facing the issue of the border lines extending beyond the points where they meet. i know that by doing "draw=none" i can turn these off, but i prefer the borders. is there an obvious fix for this? (also, I have seen rounded corners, but I'm not wanting to go this route either)

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[border=.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{black}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid, font=\sffamily, line width=.2mm]

\draw[draw=white, fill=blue!65, yslant=-0.5] (5,5) rectangle (6,6);

\draw[draw=white, fill=blue!95, yslant=0.5] (6,-1) rectangle (7,-0);

\draw[draw=white, fill=blue!45, yslant=0.5, xslant=-1] (6,0) rectangle (7,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: problem]

Also, here's a screen grab of the problem (it happens on other corners too):

Comment: Whoa!  I didn't mean to unilaterally close this!  Obviously, the rules have changed since I last voted to close a question.  If the linked question doesn't answer your problem, edit your question to explain why and it'll get reopened.

Comment: See also my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30102/86

Comment: @LoopSpace I'll delete my answer, then, since this is a duplicate. Does your clipping approach work here? Slants are being used here for the sides of the cube.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, the clipping approach does work here.