Draw stroke only outside of the path in TikZ
For the following figure, I would like to draw only outside of the path, such that the stroke does not overlap with the fill.

\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define the coordinates for your path
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (2, 1);
\coordinate (E) at (3, 1);
\coordinate (G) at (2, 2);
\coordinate (C) at (0, 2);

% Stroke draws both inside and outside of path
\path[draw,thin,save path=\cshape] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path[fill=red!50,use path=\cshape];

% several small paths defined and filled inscribed in \cshape
\fill[white] (0.2, 0.3) -- (0.8, 0.6) -- (0.4, 1) -- cycle;
% several small paths defined and filled inscribed in \cshape

\def\lenTN{3.5} % computed only during small paths being defined

\path[draw=black,thin,use path=\cshape]; % display purpose only
\path[draw,line width=\lenTN,blue!50,opacity=0.6,use path=\cshape];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Note that \lenTN cannot be computed in advance and thus drawing with line width=\lenTN can only occur after all fills are done.
I am aware of this solution that uses pgfdecoration to stroke outside the path. But is only seems to work for regular shapes. For example, the output for my coordinate points looks miserably wrong with following code:

\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections,decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{stroke outside path}{initial}{%
  \state{initial}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100,next state=iterate]
  {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  }%
  \state{iterate}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/100]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.5\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
  }%
  \state{final}{%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgflinewidth}{.5\pgflinewidth}}{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
  }%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Define the coordinates for your path
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (2, 1);
\coordinate (E) at (3, 1);
\coordinate (G) at (2, 2);
\coordinate (C) at (0, 2);

% Stroke draws both inside and outside of path
\path[fill=red!50] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\fill[white] (0.2, 0.3) -- (0.8, 0.6) -- (0.4, 1) -- cycle;
\def\lenTN{3.5} % assume ! (it is infact computed)
\draw [decoration=stroke outside path, decorate, line width = \lenTN] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\draw [red](A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I believe one solution has to do with scaling the path just so that it expands by half the \lenTN offset from the centre. But the process of computing that exact scaling factor and implementing it is unbeknown to me. Could anyone offer the solution or an alternative (for the time being) ?

You could clip away the inner part of the stroke.

Related: Q133655

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66558/14500

do you actually need to fill the smaller shape with white? or do you just want it not filled with red? because you could then just use a single path. (I haven't worked out whether this would solve the problem, because I'm not sure if white is just an example.)

Use layers. Put the path on a separate layer behind the main layer.

@cfr Yes I want inner smaller shape/s all be filled in white.

but do they need to be filled with white or just not filled with red?

The simplest trick come to my mind is: drawing the second stroke before filling the shape.

\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % Define the coordinates for your path
        \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
        \coordinate (B) at (2, 1);
        \coordinate (E) at (3, 1);
        \coordinate (G) at (2, 2);
        \coordinate (C) at (0, 2);
        
        % Stroke draws both inside and outside of path
        \path[draw,thin,save path=\cshape] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
        \path[draw, line width=5pt, blue!50, opacity=0.6, use path=\cshape]; % <--- Here
        \path[fill=red!50,use path=\cshape];
        \fill[white] (0.2, 0.3) -- (0.8, 0.6) -- (0.4, 1) -- cycle;
        \def\lenTN{3.5} % assume ! (it is infact computed)
        \path[draw=black,thin,use path=\cshape]; % display purpose only
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It works in general but, my use case is different. I have a precise line width (defined as lenTN) requirement that composes the border of the large shape. Adding to the complexity, the lenTN can be computed only during the later few steps after filling small shape (the white triangle).

@dd_rookie Half of that line width fall inside the path. So define lenTN twice of your precise line width

The idea you suggest requires me to first compute paths of small inscribed shapes and just store them, given the paths only of large shape so that line width gets computed too. I could then actually draw the large stroke using line width, fill it and then fill paths of small inscribed shapes (in that order). It works for me. Thank you.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1);
\coordinate (E) at (3,1);
\coordinate (G) at (2,2);
\coordinate (C) at (0,2);
\draw[fill=red!50, preaction={draw=blue!30, line width=3.5pt}] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\fill[white] (0.2,0.3) -- (0.8,0.6) -- (0.4,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



That should require knowledge of \draw line width prior to \fill -ing all inscribed paths (i have just presented one but there are several) which, unfortunately, is not a privilage for me.

Shortest and Simplest solution!

@hpekristiansen It works if I save just the paths of all small inscribed shapes and obtain the line width and only at last fill them after drawing large shape. So, for the job, its a win. But there has to be a solution where one shouldn't have to reuse the path.

Combining the nfold solution with a reverse clip would allow you to first define the white areas and then fill and stroke the big polygon at the end.
Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold, ext.misc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{offset/.code=\tikz@addmode{\pgfgetpath\tikz@temp\pgfsetpath\pgfutil@empty\pgfoffsetpath\tikz@temp{#1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define the coordinates for your path
\coordinate (A) at (0, 0)
 coordinate (B) at (2, 1)
 coordinate (E) at (3, 1)
 coordinate (G) at (2, 2)
 coordinate (C) at (0, 2);

\draw[help lines, step=1] (-.25,-.25) grid (3.25,2.25);
\clip[reverse clip=clockwise]
  (0.2, 0.3) -- (0.8, 0.6) -- (0.4, 1) -- cycle
  % and more …
;
\tikzset{overlay=false} % clipping disables bounding box calculation, re-enable
\def\lenTN{3.5pt}
\path[
  offset=+-.5\pgflinewidth, line width=\lenTN,
  draw=blue!50, fill=red!50,
] (A) -- (B) -- (E) -- (G) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

