# Aux file won't finish writing

Tags: auxiliary-files, bibdesk

I've used Bibdesk to write a bibliography, and I've simply copied the cite commands into my `.tex` file, so I know they're right.  I have at the bottom of my `.tex` file simply:

```
\bibliography{ref}
```

Somehow, I get an error from my `.aux` file:

```
Undefined control sequence
I.86 \citatio
```

Indeed, my `.aux` file stops writing in the middle, and the last line of it is simply

```
\citatio
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! I'm a bit confused. If you know everything is right, then obviously either there is a serious bug in the packages you are using or in LaTeX or in TeX. Or your installation of TeX is screwed up. Since we have to take your word for the first point (no code supplied), you don't tell us what packages etc. you are using, and we know nothing about your installation, how exactly may we be of assistance? We need to see code which produces the problem. Please prepare a small document (minimal) with just enough code so that when we compile it, we'll get the same error.

Comment: The command `\citatio` isn't defined by plain LaTeX. I suspect there's a typo in your sources and _possibly_ one of the packages you're using. I suggest you remove all `aux` files and remove any reference to `\citatio` in your sources. If recompiling then doesn't work, try to narrow down the problem. This can be done easily by copying your source to a temporary file (`tmp.tex`) and using the temporary file and the procedure suggested in the answers to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/how-to-trace-latex-errors-efficiently).

Comment: This looks like that you kill the process mid-way somehow, truncating the `aux` file in the middle of the string `\citation`. We really need to know more about what you're doing. Could you maybe construct a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, I had the same problem, and removing the offending aux file fixed it. I think you should therefore post your suggestion as an answer. If you don't want to, do you mind if I do?

Comment: @Vectornaut Feel free to go ahead.