# How to read and fix latex errors?

Tags: errors, compilation-error

So if I get an error of the form

```
Argument of \beamer@decodegobble has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.309 \end{frame}
 I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.?
```

or

```
Runaway argument?

! Paragraph ended before \beamer@decodegobble was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.309 \end{frame}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Like if I don't find a problem of the form on line 309 how do I look for solutions at this point?  I've never understood how to read latex errors.

Comment: Try this method, it seems to work. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125404/90297 TL;DR the error can be anywhere before line 309

Comment: Beamer frames are actually a sort of command and the content an argument.  This means that errors in the frame are often reported only when latex sees the end frame command. So check the complete frame.