# Why do I get `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. l.2 gdef @abspage@last{1}` starting from second compilation?

Tags: errors

I have a simple TeX file like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\printcsnameof #1{
    \escapechar=-1
    \string #1
}

\printcsnameof \test

\end{document}
```

When I compile it the first time, it works well and print `test` on the page.

However, from the second run, it raises the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ->\errmessage  LaTeX Error: Missing \protect \begin {document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help\@err@                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
l.2 g
   def @abspage@last{1}
?
```

What is going on?

Comment: I did actually encounter this issue before, but I debugged it myself, and can't find a similar question on the site (searching by the error message) so post here in case someone search for the error message online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the code modifies the value of `escapechar` globally, which makes the behavior of the code that runs at the end of the document that writes to the `.aux` file incorrect.

If you check the `.aux` file, the content would be

```
\relax 
gdef @abspage@last{1}
```

Solution:

- Modify the code so that it does not modify `escapechar` globally, e.g.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}

  \def\printcsnameof #1{%
      {%
          \escapechar=-1
          \string #1%
      }%
  }

  \printcsnameof \test

  \end{document}
  ```
- **Delete the old `.aux` file** (otherwise you'll keep getting the error message)
- Recompile the file.

With the corrected file, the `.aux` file content should be

```
\relax 
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

with the `\` before `gdef` and `@abspage@last`.

Comment: you are inserting spurious spaces.

Comment: you might want to add some % as 
your printcsnameof adds 4 space tokens each time

Comment: Okay fixed (got too used to expl3 programming) – (note.the line without `%` is because of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/when-is-it-harmful-to-add-percent-character-at-end-of-lines-in-a-newcommand-or?noredirect=1&lq=1)