# Inclined Planes

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a Free Body Diagram in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49356/creating-a-free-body-diagram-in-tikz)

As teachers of our department (physics and chemistry) that we do not like books which are sold in bookstores of our subject, we decided to make our own book with LaTeX. We did one last year and it was quite successful for us and for the students themselves.

A part of the subject are inclined planes, so I'd like to know if there is any "easy" way to do them, because having to be operating in a paper apart the coordinates of the points of all figures of the drawings is a arduous and tedious task.

The visual examples would be like this. (Examples colors are irrelevant)

[image: Inclined Plane]
[image]

Comment: look at this
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49356/creating-a-free-body-diagram-in-tikz/49407#49407

Comment: Please do take a look at the question linked by rpapa as it looks very similar to what you want to do.  If that doesn't help you, please edit your question to explain why not - or if it helps a bit but then you get stuck then it might be best to ask a new question about that sticking point.  If it does help, we'll probably close this one as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: (To everyone else: remember to leave time for the questioner to check out the linked question before voting to close as a duplicate.)

Comment: Even with the link provided, I think that making these diagrams with pure Tikz (even with a semi-WYSIWYG editor) requires high skills with it. So I think that the best option will be to use Inkscape and then transform it afterwords to Tikz. Thank you.

Comment: In that case you can try your luck with `dia` also.