# Spurious space from \tdplotsetmaincoords

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, draw

The MWE below results is spurious space due to the use of `\tdplotsetmaincoords`:

[image]

The red is the bounding box and the gray box is from `\fbox{}`.

Including an `\unskip\unskip` (commented out in the MWE) does resolve the problem, but wondering if there is a better solution.

Is this a bug or is there a reason for this spacing?

### Notes:

- Moving the `\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}` to be *before* `\begin{document}` also resolves the problem, but this won't easily work for me as my figures use the `standalone` class and are included in other documents -- thus I need to have that setting localized with each figure.

### References:

- The code for the cube drawing is from [How to draw a cube with TikZ where all faces have a distinct color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29342/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [
        draw=red, thick,
    ]
    ([shift={(-1pt,-1pt)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle 
    ([shift={(1pt,1pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{%
  %% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29342/4301
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}%
  %\unskip\unskip% <----- HACK which fixes the problem.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Py) -- (Pyz) -- (Pz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Px) -- (Pxy) -- (Py) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Px) -- (Pxz) -- (Pz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (Pz) -- (Pyz) -- (P) -- (Pxz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] (Px) -- (Pxy) -- (P) -- (Pxz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.5] (Py) -- (Pxy) -- (P) -- (Pyz) -- cycle;
    
    \DrawBoundingBox
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that this will get fixed in `tikz-3dplot`.  The last update was in 2012 and there are no contact details of the author in the manual.

Comment: @HenriMenke After quick research, it seems I have found useful informations for contact the author of the `tikz-3dplot` package. From https://heinjd.wordpress.com/category/latex/, I read in the bottom "Some time ago, I developed the 3dplot package". On https://heinjd.wordpress.com/about/, I read "Jeff recently received a Ph.D. from the University of Manitoba Department of Physics and Astronomy." Finally, I found this *JPL* page: https://science.jpl.nasa.gov/people/Hein/, with coordinate and CV. Correspond to the informations of the `tikz-3dplot` author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are spurious spaces in the code. Notify the maintainer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [
        draw=red, thick,
    ]
    ([shift={(-1pt,-1pt)}]current bounding box.south west) rectangle
    ([shift={(1pt,1pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
}
\renewcommand{\tdplotsetmaincoords}[2]{%
%perform some trig for the display transformation
%
%
%store the user-specified angles for possible future use
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotmaintheta}{#1}% <------ changed
\pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotmainphi}{#2}% <------- changed
%
%
\tdplotcalctransformmainscreen
%
%now here is where the output is performed
\tikzset{tdplot_main_coords/.style={x={(\raarot cm,\rbarot cm)},y={(\rabrot cm, \rbbrot cm)},z={(\racrot cm, \rbcrot cm)}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt 
\fbox{%
  %% code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29342/4301
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}%
  %\unskip\unskip% <----- HACK which fixes the problem.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{1.414213}{54.68636}{45}

    \draw[fill=gray!50,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Py) -- (Pyz) -- (Pz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Px) -- (Pxy) -- (Py) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.5] (O) -- (Px) -- (Pxz) -- (Pz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=green,fill opacity=0.5] (Pz) -- (Pyz) -- (P) -- (Pxz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red,fill opacity=0.5] (Px) -- (Pxy) -- (P) -- (Pxz) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=magenta,fill opacity=0.5] (Py) -- (Pxy) -- (P) -- (Pyz) -- cycle;

    \DrawBoundingBox
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that it is an easy fix in the `tikz-pgf` code. Sadly have to wait a few minutes to accept the answer.

Comment: the command is in tikz-3dplot, not tikz directly.