# 3D projection of a text with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem with the text showing the inter-elements spacing, I would like it to be in the same orientation as my structure, is there an easy Tikz solution ?

[image]

Code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{40}{-30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\def \r{0.5};
\def \d{1.5};
\def \nx{2};
\def \ny{2};
\def \bord{0.11};
\def \hsub{0.1};

\definecolor{cuivre}{rgb}{0.9,0.7,0.4};
\definecolor{ceram}{rgb}{0.92,0.95,0.95};

%masse
\filldraw[fill=gray] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,-\hsub) 
        --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
        --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
        --++ (-\nx*\d+\r/2,0,0)
        -- cycle; 

%cadre
\filldraw[fill=cuivre] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
        --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
        --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
        --++ (-\nx*\d+\r/2,0,0)
        -- cycle; 

%sub1
\filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
        --++ (0,0,-\hsub)
        --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
        --++ (0,0,\hsub)
        -- cycle;

%sub2
\filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
        --++ (0,0,-\hsub)
        --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
        --++ (0,0,\hsub)
        -- cycle;

%trous
\foreach \x in {1,...,\nx}{
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\ny}{
        \filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d*\x,\d*\y,0) circle (\r);  
    }
}

\foreach \x in {2,...,\nx}{
    \foreach \y in {2,...,\ny}{
        \filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d*\x-\d/2,\d*\y-\d/2,0) 
        circle (\r);  
    }
}

%espace inter trou 1
\draw[dashed] (\d, \nx*\d,\hsub) --++ (0,1.5,0);
\draw[dashed] (2*\d, \nx*\d,\hsub) --++ (0,1.5,0);
\draw[<->] (\d, \nx*\d+1.5,\hsub) -- (2*\d, \nx*\d+1.5,\hsub) node
[font=\footnotesize,midway, fill=white, anchor=center]{1.5mm};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is quite easy, just add it as my answer in this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46682/making-a-3d-colored-pyramid-in-tikz/49851#49851, the key is simply to add the new coordinate system to the node as well. However, getting the sizes "correct" while changing coordinate system can be quite tricky. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `sloped` as argument of your last node. `above` makes the text not cross the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{40}{-30}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\def \r{0.5};
\def \d{1.5};
\def \nx{2};
\def \ny{2};
\def \bord{0.11};
\def \hsub{0.1};

\definecolor{cuivre}{rgb}{0.9,0.7,0.4};
\definecolor{ceram}{rgb}{0.92,0.95,0.95};

%masse
\filldraw[fill=gray] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,-\hsub) 
    --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
    --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
    --++ (-\nx*\d+\r/2,0,0)
    -- cycle; 

%cadre
\filldraw[fill=cuivre] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
    --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
    --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
    --++ (-\nx*\d+\r/2,0,0)
    -- cycle; 

%sub1
\filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
    --++ (0,0,-\hsub)
    --++ (0,\ny*\d-\r/2,0)
    --++ (0,0,\hsub)
    -- cycle;

%sub2
\filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d-\r-\bord,\d-\r-\bord,0) 
    --++ (0,0,-\hsub)
    --++ (\nx*\d-\r/2,0,0)
    --++ (0,0,\hsub)
    -- cycle;

%trous
\foreach \x in {1,...,\nx}{
\foreach \y in {1,...,\ny}{
    \filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d*\x,\d*\y,0) circle (\r);  
}
}

\foreach \x in {2,...,\nx}{
\foreach \y in {2,...,\ny}{
    \filldraw[fill=ceram] (\d*\x-\d/2,\d*\y-\d/2,0) 
    circle (\r);  
}
}

%espace inter trou 1
\draw[dashed] (\d, \nx*\d,\hsub) --++ (0,1.5,0);
\draw[dashed] (2*\d, \nx*\d,\hsub) --++ (0,1.5,0);
\draw[<->] (\d, \nx*\d+1.5,\hsub) -- (2*\d, \nx*\d+1.5,\hsub) node
[font=\footnotesize,midway, fill=white, anchor=center,sloped, above]{1.5mm}; %here's the trick

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make it in perspective, not only rotated?

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As Sigur mentioned previously, I was looking for a real 3D projection, not only a slopped text, but that's a good start.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, simply add the projection coordinate system to the node as well, see my comment above.