# Tikz with equation regions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to plot in `tikz` the below constraint on the unit cube defined by the region x, y, z in [-1, 1].

x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 * x * y * z <= 1

I found [Making a 3D colored pyramid in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46682/making-a-3d-colored-pyramid-in-tikz) though it doesn't work with the above constraint.

The following is the graph from http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2684832. I'd prefer it to look more "modern" or similar to the 3d pyramid style.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: A hard candy in a cube?

Comment: bonus points if you use jolly rancher colors

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show the code changes that you have tried in adapting the example that you linked and which problems/errors/wrong results you encountered when you adapted that code?

Comment: I ended up doing it in gnuplot.