# Making a black hole and information

Tags: diagrams, 3d

I would like to make the picture similar to the following to represent information in a black hole horizon and black hole inside the sphere in tex. I can make a sphere but making the discrete bits seem hard, I cant get it looking nice like the image at all. Any ideas?

[image: Black Hole]
[image]

Comment: Maybe try adapting [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/3d-axis-and-polyhedron-with-line-segment-towards-origin), which discusses how to draw the projection of a polyhedron. Your polyhedron is quite complex, but it looks to me like a [truncated icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) with faces subdivided into triangles. So I guess if you can calculate the coordinates of the vertices, you can apply that question.

Comment: For a complicated figure as this one I'd break out [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net)'s 3D package. It can use the same fonts and colors as (La)TeX does, and it's C-like syntax with 3D points (triples) is very friendly.