# How can I draw development of a polyhedron?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I have some pictures http://www.mediafire.com/view/?58gs6ye0zf149fv
How can I draw development of polyherons in Tex? Please help me.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: A question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with [Drawing polyhedra using TikZ with semi-transparent and shading effect](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect)

Comment: Yes, I saw. But I want to draw development of this polyhedrons.

Comment: So you want to draw polyhedra step-by-step, e.g. add a new face in every slide?

Comment: TomBombadil: I guess the OP wants to draw [this](http://imgur.com/QpCCb). @minthao_2011: Am I right?

Comment: Only regular polyhedra or arbitrary ones (with more than one kind of surface)?

Comment: Dear Claudio Fiandrino, you are right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a solution for regular convex polyhedra:

- the triangle solution (tetraeder, octaeder, ikosaeder) uses redifinition of the coordinate axes (0°, 60°). You have to specify the coordinates of the lower right (`\uptrig`) or upper right (`\downtrig`) corners.
- the square solution (hexaeder) is straight forward as it only needs to draw squares
- for the pentagon solution (dodecaeder) there are 10 directions (see picture). For both `\uppent` and `\downpent` you have to specify the path to the destination. So `{10,1,10,7}` means do go each one step in directions 10,1,10 and 7

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% === regular triangles ===
\newcommand{\uptrig}[2][blue!50!gray,draw=white,thick]% [options], list of coordinates e.g {1,2},{1,3},{4,2}
{   \foreach \c in {#2}
    \fill[#1] (\c) -- ($(\c)+(1,0)$) -- ($(\c)+(0,1)$) -- cycle;
}
\newcommand{\downtrig}[2][blue!50!gray,draw=white,thick]% [options], list of coordinates e.g {1,2},{1,3},{4,2}
{   \foreach \c in {#2}
    \fill[#1] (\c) -- ($(\c)+(1,0)$) -- ($(\c)+(1,-1)$) -- cycle;
}

% === squares ===
\newcommand{\squares}[2][blue!50!gray,draw=white,thick]% [options], list of coordinates e.g {1,2},{1,3},{4,2}
{   \foreach \c in {#2}
    \fill[#1] (\c) rectangle ($(\c)+(1,1)$) -- cycle;
}

% === regular pentagon ==
\newcommand{\downpent}[2][blue!50!gray,draw=white,thick]% [options], list of direction steps e.g {10/2/1/1}
{   
    \coordinate (temp) at (0,0);
    \foreach \p in {#2}
    {   \foreach \s in \p
        {   \coordinate (temp) at ($(temp)+(\s*36-18:1)$);
        }
        \fill[#1] ($(temp)+(54:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(126:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(198:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(270:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(342:0.618)$) -- cycle;
        \coordinate (temp) at (0,0);
    }
}
\newcommand{\uppent}[2][blue!50!gray,draw=white,thick]% [options], list of coordinates e.g {1,2},{1,3},{4,2}
{   
    \coordinate (temp) at (0,0);
    \foreach \p in {#2}
    {   \foreach \s in \p
        {   \coordinate (temp) at ($(temp)+(\s*36-18:1)$);
        }
        \fill[#1] ($(temp)+(-54:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(-126:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(-198:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(-270:0.618)$) -- ($(temp)+(-342:0.618)$) -- cycle;
        \coordinate (temp) at (0,0);
    }
}

\begin{document}
\section*{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(0:1cm)},
    y={(60:1cm)},
    scale=2
]
    \uptrig[red,draw=white,thick]{{0,0},{1,0},{-1,1},{0,-1}}
    \downtrig{{-1,1},{0,1},{0,0},{0,-1}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \squares[green!50!gray,dashed,draw= white]{{0,0},{-1,0},{1,0},{0,1},{0,-1},{0,-2}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \downpent[orange,draw=white,thick]{{2},{4},{6},{8},{10},{10,1,10}}
    \uppent[cyan!50!blue,draw=white,thick]{{},{10,1},{10,1,10,3},{10,1,10,1},{10,1,10,9},{10,1,10,7}}
    \foreach \a [count=\c] in {18,54,...,342} \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (\a:1cm) node[label=\a:\c] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]