# tikz-cd: Shade faces of commutative cube

Tags: 3d, shading, tikz-cd

I would like to "shade" the faces of a commutative cube drawn using `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
&
P
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{t}
\ar{rr}{t'}
\ar[]{dd}[near end]{t}
& & R''
\ar{dd}{}
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{}
\\
R
\ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{}
\ar{dd}[swap]{}
& & S''
\\
&
R'
\ar[near start]{rr}{}
\ar[sloped, near end]{dl}{}
& & S
\ar{dl}
\\
S'
\ar{rr}
& & P'
\ar[crossing over, leftarrow, near start]{uu}{}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One subtlety is that the vertices of this "cube" are not visible. However, there is a notional location for each vertex and I would like the shading to extend to that notional location. Really I'm just after a way of visually highlighting a face of the cube.

The shading should be quite transparent so that any edges of the cube that lie behind are still visible, and the arrows that lie along the edges of the shaded face are still clear.

Roughly speaking, I would like the effect of  [Drawing polyhedra using TikZ with semi-transparent and shading effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204), but staying as much as possible within `tikz-cd`. I have a bunch of existing diagrams that I would like to animate by highlighting various faces in this way.

Is this possible, or would I need to rewrite my diagrams to use Tikz directly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\foreach \Valor/\Nombre in   
{%
  tikz@f@1-2-1/a,tikz@f@1-1-2/b,tikz@f@1-1-4/c,tikz@f@1-2-3/d,%
  tikz@f@1-4-1/e,tikz@f@1-3-2/f,tikz@f@1-3-4/g,tikz@f@1-4-3/h%
}
{
\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Valor);
}
\fill[pur,opacity=0.3] 
  (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\fill[cof,opacity=0.3] 
  (a) -- (d) -- (h) -- (e) -- cycle;
\fill[greeo,opacity=0.3] 
  (h) -- (d) -- (c) -- (g) -- cycle;
  }
]
&
P
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{t}
\ar{rr}{t'}
\ar[]{dd}[near end]{t}
& & R''
\ar{dd}{}
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{}
\\
R
\ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{}
\ar{dd}[swap]{}
& & S''
\\
&
R'
\ar[near start]{rr}{}
\ar[sloped, near end]{dl}{}
& & S
\ar{dl}
\\
S'
\ar{rr}
& & P'
\ar[crossing over, leftarrow, near start]{uu}{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to place a coordinate at each of the nodes in the diagram and then use those coordinates to do the filling; this is done using the `execute at end picture` key.

## The internal numbering schema

Each node in a `tikz-cd` diagram has an internal name of the form

```
tikz@f@<number>-<row>-<column>
```

where `<number>` is the number of the `tikz-cd` diagram, `<row>` and `<column>` are the row and column, respectively, of the node. For example, the node labeled `R` in the above diagram (assuming it is the first `tikz-cd` diagram) would be

```
tikz@f@1-2-1
```

Had it been the 13th diagram, the internal name for `R` would've been

```
tikz@f@13-2-1
```

For example, the following shows, for each node, both its internal name and its new user-defined name. This is helpful if you want some guide during the filling process:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\foreach \Valor/\Nombre/\Posi in   
{%
  tikz@f@1-2-1/a/left,tikz@f@1-1-2/b/left,tikz@f@1-1-4/c/right,tikz@f@1-2-3/d/right,%
  tikz@f@1-4-1/e/left,tikz@f@1-3-2/f/left,tikz@f@1-3-4/g/right,tikz@f@1-4-3/h/right%
}
{
\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Valor);
\node[\Posi=10pt,align=center] at (\Nombre) {\Valor\\ new name:\Nombre};
}
}
]
&
P
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{t}
\ar{rr}{t'}
\ar[]{dd}[near end]{t}
& & R''
\ar{dd}{}
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{}
\\
R
\ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{}
\ar{dd}[swap]{}
& & S''
\\
&
R'
\ar[near start]{rr}{}
\ar[sloped, near end]{dl}{}
& & S
\ar{dl}
\\
S'
\ar{rr}
& & P'
\ar[crossing over, leftarrow, near start]{uu}{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to keep finding the currect number of your diagram, you can use the associated internal count(er) `\tikz@fig@count`, but then something like

```
tikz@f@1-2-1
```

transforms into

```
tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-2-1
```

and the resulting code is rather cumbersome:

```
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzcd}[
execute at end picture={
\foreach \Valor/\Nombre in   
{%
  tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-2-1/a,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-1-2/b,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-1-4/c,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-2-3/d,%
  tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-4-1/e,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-3-2/f,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-3-4/g,tikz@f@\the\tikz@fig@count-4-3/h%
}
{
\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Valor);
}
\fill[cyan,opacity=0.15] 
  (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
\fill[orange,opacity=0.2] 
  (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
\fill[green,opacity=0.12] 
  (e) -- (a) -- (d) -- (h) -- cycle;
}
]
&
P
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{t}
\ar{rr}{t'}
\ar[]{dd}[near end]{t}
& & R''
\ar{dd}{}
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{}
\\
R
\ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{}
\ar{dd}[swap]{}
& & S''
\\
&
R'
\ar[near start]{rr}{}
\ar[sloped, near end]{dl}{}
& & S
\ar{dl}
\\
S'
\ar{rr}
& & P'
\ar[crossing over, leftarrow, near start]{uu}{}
\end{tikzcd}
\makeatother
```

## A better approach

Using the `alias` key (and the standard `|[...]|` syntax for passing keys to nodes in a matrix), you can place easy-to-remember names to the nodes so you don't have to fiddle with the internal names and can use those simpler names for the shading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={
\foreach \Nombre in  {A,B,...,H}
  {\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Nombre.center);}
\fill[pur,opacity=0.3] 
  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
\fill[greeo,opacity=0.3] 
  (A) -- (D) -- (H) -- (E) -- cycle;
\fill[cof,opacity=0.3] 
  (H) -- (D) -- (C) -- (G) -- cycle;
}]
&
|[alias=B]|P
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{t}
\ar{rr}{t'}
\ar[]{dd}[near end]{t}
& & |[alias=C]|R''
\ar{dd}{}
\ar{dl}[swap, sloped, near start]{}
\\
|[alias=A]|R
\ar[crossing over]{rr}[near start]{}
\ar{dd}[swap]{}
& & |[alias=D]|S''
\\
&
|[alias=F]|R'
\ar[near start]{rr}{}
\ar[sloped, near end]{dl}{}
& & |[alias=G]|S
\ar{dl}
\\
|[alias=E]|S'
\ar{rr}
& & |[alias=H]|P'
\ar[crossing over, leftarrow, near start]{uu}{}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Use of backgrounds

For diagrams in which `crossing over` or `description` are not used, one can refine the answer doing the filling in a `background` layer; in this way, even with `opacity=1` the filling doesn't affect labels nor arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
execute at end picture={
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \foreach \Nombre in  {A,B,...,E}
    {\coordinate (\Nombre) at (\Nombre.center);}
  \fill[pur!40] 
    (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
]
  |[alias=A]|A
  \ar[rr,"f"]\ar[dd,"k"]\ar[dr,"\alpha"]
& & 
  |[alias=B]|B\ar[dd,"l",swap] 
\\
&
  |[alias=E]|E\ar[ur,"\beta"]\ar[dr,"\delta"] 
& 
\\
  |[alias=C]|C\ar[rr,"g"]\ar[ur,"\gamma"] 
& & 
  |[alias=D]|D 
\\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Since I can not favorite the answer I favorited the question. What is the meaning of `1-2-1`? I guess that entry `(2,1)` but what about the first `1`?

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I had in mind! Great. Is there a way to determine what coordinates to use for 1-2-1, etc? I'm starting with trial-and-error, but that's proving rather difficult...

Comment: @Roly It's easy. I am on the mobile now, but as soon as I have a computer in front, I'll add a remark. You can even use the alias key to make the naming easier. I'll also add this option.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that would be very useful. My experiments so far are producing strange results (the vertices of the coloured regions don't seem to line up with the vertices of the cube), so maybe things will become clearer once I know what I'm doing with the coordinates.

Comment: @Roly I added some explanations on the naming schema and also an option using `alias`. Let me know if this clarifies things.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks! I added an explanation about the meaning of the internal names (as you correctly guessed, the last two numbers in `<number>-<row>-<column>`  give the row and column of the node; the first `<number>` refers to the number of the `tikz-cd` environment.)

Comment: Ah, *that* explains why my shaded regions were coming out the same shape as parts of earlier figures...I gave up trying to figure it out, but now it makes some kind of sense. I'll try your amended solution tomorrow. Also thanks for the |[...]| tip, I needed to know how to pass keys to nodes in a tikz-cd diagram anyway!

Comment: Ok, tried it (with the aliaising solution) and now it all works fine. Thanks again - great answer.

Comment: @Roly You're welcome. Glad to hear everythink works OK now.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, thanks so much for this real lecture on the subject. I don't know if it is there already but you could contribute to add this in the user guide. Congs.