# Filling of diagrams using tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following diagram:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
   x \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr] \&  \& y \arrow[dl]  \\ 
    \& z \&   \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

and I would like to use:

```
\fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue],
```

to fill it with that pattern. What is the correct way to do this? I am just getting errors every time I try this.

Comment: Please add the complete code of a small document that shows what you have tried and that produces the errors that you mention in your post. As you surely know as an [experienced member of this community](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/74290/abellan?tab=questions), an MWE helps us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's ugly-looking, however, if this is what you want...

You can use the `fit` library and `execute at end picture` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, patterns}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, execute at end picture={ 
      \node[rectangle, draw, blue,
                pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue,
                fit={(tikz@f@1-1-1) (tikz@f@1-1-3)  (tikz@f@1-2-2)}
            ] 
        {};
        }  
      ]
    x \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr] \&  \& y \arrow[dl]  \\ 
    \& z \&   \\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]
And if someone would like the pattern in the background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, patterns, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&, execute at end picture={ 
      \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
      \node[rectangle, draw, blue,
                pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue,
                fit={(tikz@f@1-1-1) (tikz@f@1-1-3)  (tikz@f@1-2-2)}
            ] 
        {};  
      \end{scope}}]
    x \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr] \&  \& y \arrow[dl]  \\ 
    \& z \&   \\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:
The original version of this answer used `overlay` but it is not needed and caused vartical overlay with the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, patterns}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}[remember picture, overlay, ampersand replacement=\&]
    x \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr] \&  \& y \arrow[dl]  \\ 
    \& z \&   \\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
        \node[rectangle, draw, blue,
                pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue,
                fit={(tikz@f@1-1-1) (tikz@f@1-1-3)  (tikz@f@1-2-2)}
            ] 
        {};
    }
    \]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution with `execute at end picture`. Unfortunately I can't up-vote twice :-(.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you! I realized the original solution was wrong only yesterday because someone upvoted it :)

Answer (score 6):

I could be tempted to close as duplicate of the question you referred to in the first question you posted about this:  [tikz-cd: Shade faces of commutative cube](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256835/tikz-cd-shade-faces-of-commutative-cube)

This is basically the same as what is described in the last part of Gonzalo's answer, but using your `\fill` command instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[
  ampersand replacement=\&,
  execute at end picture={
    \scoped[on background layer]
    \fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue] (a.center) -- (b.center) -- (c.center) -- cycle;
  }]
   |[alias=a]|x \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr] \&  \& |[alias=b]|y \arrow[dl]  \\ 
    \& |[alias=c]|z \&   
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As suplement to the first solution of the [CarLaTeX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360083/filling-of-diagrams-using-tikzcd/360152#360152). Small variations are:

- style for node with pattern is defined by the `\tikzset`
- for pattern is used `pattern.meta` packages,
- defined is matrix name

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                patterns.meta,
                shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
F/.style = {draw=blue, inner ysep=0pt, fit=#1,
            postaction={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={2pt},
                                       line width=0.25pt]},
                        pattern color=blue!50, semitransparent} }
        }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[65]
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[
every matrix/.append style = {name=m},
execute at end picture = {
    \node[F = (m-1-1) (m-1-3) (m-2-2) ] {};
                        }% end of execute at end picture
                    ]
x \ar[rr] \ar[dr]   &   & y \ar[dl] \\
                    & z &        
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]