# Draw permutahedron of order 3 with tikz but without sagetex

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

How do I draw a [Permutahedron of order 3](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Permutohedron_order_3.svg/600px-Permutohedron_order_3.svg.png) in tikz in 3 dimensions? I'd like to get a readable code which draws a planar projection of a 3D object rather than unreadable (hence unmaintainbale) automatically generated output. This is slightly more complicated than [Drawing polyhedra using TikZ with semi-transparent and shading effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/drawing-polyhedra-using-tikz-with-semi-transparent-and-shading-effect)
as we wish to color-fill a nontriangular, nonrectangular 2D object embedded into a 3D object.

As of today, sagetex in not available on the distributions I am using, so I am wishing to do without it.

Comment: [SagemathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) offers free accounts that have `sagetex` and other features built in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use PGFPlots for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    view={110}{30},
    xmin=1, xmax=3,
    ymin=1, ymax=3,
    zmin=1, zmax=3,
    axis equal image
]
\addplot3 [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] table {
x y z
1 2 3
2 1 3
3 1 2
3 2 1
2 3 1
1 3 2
}--cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @LeonMeier: Thanks, I edited the MWE to include the `compat` setting. It doesn't change anything about the output in this case, but it's good practice anyway.